# Problem importing WFS layer into QGIS

Tags: wfs, inspire, ows

I am trying to import a WFS layer into QGIS. I tried the normal procedure, *Add WFS Layer*, and it does not display any boxes. When I click on Add, it throws an error:

> Layer is not valid: The layer restrictToRequestBBOX='1'
>   srsname='EPSG:4326' typename='bu:Building'
>   url='http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/INSPIRE/wfsBU.aspx' version='auto'
>   table="" sql= nis not valid and cannot be added to the map

I also tried the WFS 2.0 Plugin and in this case, I was able to download some vectorial data which seemed to be ok, but only if I was zooming very close to extract some features. When I zoom out to get the extent I need (or even a bit more), I get the following error:

[image: ows error]

> OWS Exception returned from the WFS: Area of extension out of limits.

However, I know there is data beyond my bounding box.

Am I doing something wrong? I also changed the EPSG several times and it did not work either.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [service description](http://www.catastro.minhap.gob.es/webinspire/documentos/inspire-bu-WFS.pdf) of the WFS the following rules apply to the usage of the service:

> Limitaciones del servicio WFS:
>
> - Búsqueda por caja de 4km2 y 5.000 elementos
> - […]

Translated via Google Translate it means:

> WFS Service Limitations:
>
> - Search by box of 4km2 and 5,000 elements
> - […]

This means, that the extension for a single request from the client is restricted to an area of not more than 4 km², which explains your described behaviour.

Comment: Well, that makes a lot of sense then. Thanks a lot!